# How can I use java variable in jsp tag in .jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to use the value of a java variable in a jsp tag.
Currently, I am trying like this.

```
<%
String searchRowCount = request.getSession().getAttribute("rowCount").toString();
%>
<br/>
<fmt:message key="SEARCH_UPDATE.ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE" var="ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE">
<fmt:param value="<%=searchRowCount%>"/>
</fmt:message>
```

But It is not working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the best way is: not. you should keep business logic  (java code) in the servlets

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expression Language or JSTL

Using expression language:

```
<%
  String searchRowCount = request.getSession().getAttribute("rowCount").toString();
%> 

<fmt:message key="SEARCH_UPDATE.ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE" var="ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE">
    <fmt:param value="${searchRowCount}"/>
</fmt:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionScope object like this.

```
  <fmt:message key="SEARCH_UPDATE.ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE" var="ITEM_FOUND_MESSAGE">
        <fmt:param value="${sessionScope.rowCount}"/>
    </fmt:message>
```

Comment: @Manish Jangir is this work with your source code?